# Mouse Rollover event for ASP.NET control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET ImageButton control (no AJAX) with a Image_Click event that fetches data from SQL server. Now I want to add a Mouse Rollover to the Image Button that should fetch the data from the SQL server and display it on a Label.

I know you can add a Javascript Mouse Rollover event on the Image Button. 
 imgae_Button.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "myJacascriptFunction()");

How do I get the Javascript code fire Server side code to fetch the SQL data?
Can this be done?

EDIT: Clarification onclick() event not only fetches data from SQL but also writes to another table. This event has alreday been coded without AJAX.
It is the mouse rollover event that I need help with. When the user hovers over the image, data should be fetched from SQL database & displayed on a label control.

Comment: So you want the click event to be done via ajax?

Comment: So you want the onclick and onmouseover to get the same data?

Comment: onclick() will do something more involved. It involves some computations & then will add data to a SQL database.
ommouseover () event will be much simple. It will read data from the SQL database & display data on a label. But the data will keep changing depending where the mouse is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

This sure can be done, and will almost certainly involve AJAX.

In your mouse rollover event you want to define `myJavascriptFunction()` to click the image button on the users behalf, this will subsequently postback to the server ***as if*** the user had simply clicked.

You then want to place the image button and the label you want to show the answer into an [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) and ensure you stick a [`ScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) on the page too to handle the request/response.

This should achieve what you want.